# how to set max draw down per trade in pine

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, cryptocurrency, tradingview-api

hi guys so i have a cross over strategy in pine, it dosent have tp, sl
it simply buys on bullish cross over and sells at bearish

i keep it as it is without messing around with tp and sl
but i wanna set a max draw down of 5% percent that if it falls to 5 or more percent it will close the trade on candle closure

```
buy= crossunder (k,d)
sell= crossover(k,d)


// strategy
strategy.entry ("long", strategy.long, 100, when = buy) 
strategy.close ("long", when = sell)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a setup for a stop loss, which will limit per trade drawdown to 5%. Typically drawdown would be referred to overall for the strategy as a whole, which we can do too! Here is the first part though complete with an input to change it, and a plot so you can see it when in a trade.

```
stopPer = input(5.0, title='Stop Loss %', type=input.float) / 100

longStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopPer)

plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? longStop : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.red, linewidth=1, title="Long Fixed SL")   

strategy.exit(id="Close Long", stop=longStop, when=strategy.position_size > 0)
```

Comment: man this is literally amazing, I'm really grateful, thanks a lot, i added to the chart and it works like a clock now thanks alot, i wanted to ask one more qustion if you don't mind!

how accurate do you think t.v backtesting is, i am getting 1200% on 15m frame since 1st of aug is this normal? and it works only on btc chart, other charts are getting like 1-30% profit over same period of time and same t.f

Comment: That’s great, and no problem! There can be many caveats in any back testing software, but if careful steps to avoid bias and understand what causes it are taken, then results can align with expected behaviour. That said it does sound a bit strange and the return is a bit high so I would be skeptical, but without access to more information I can’t really comment further as it would be speculation. Cheers!

Comment: now its working but trades not reaching binanace sadly idk what i have made wrong, i will post the code if you get the time please check it, and i am really sorry for troubling you a lot, i am a fresh new programer

Comment: No problem! I’ll help when I can

Comment: strategy.entry ("long", strategy.long, when =buy,comment="Long", alert_message= Long) 
strategy.close ("long", when = sell, comment="Close Long", alert_message= ExitLong)
strategy.entry ("short", strategy.short, when=sell, comment="Short", alert_message= Short)
strategy.close ("short", when=buy, comment="Close Short", alert_message=ExitShort)
strategy.exit("Long TSL", "long", trail_points = 0.02, trail_offset = 0.1,alert_message=ExitLong)
strategy.exit("Short TSL", "short", trail_points = 0.02, trail_offset = 0.1, alert_message= ExitShort)

Comment: i have fild exactaly as you said, i made 2 bots one short one long, and field aler meseges i get local alert at t.v but it doesnot reach to binance or 3 commas

Comment: and i wanted to ask if you have any Udemy courses that you made or any type of pine course, i was checking your tradingview, you are a beast i would love to learn from you throw a course

Comment: We are on the wrong thread here but did you put in the {{strategy.alert_message}} part?

Comment: i have put {{strategy.alert.message}} 

Comment: man programming was not built for lawyers like my self, haha
soon lawyer bots will take over my job for this reason only

Comment: sadly still not going throw i will have to ask 3 commas support and see

Comment: Do you have the web hook in there? It’s hard to help any more with our pictures. Check the alert in TV and make sure they match the keys for 3commas and that you put the webhook URL in the alert message box as well

Comment: yeah bro sadly all is there, even the command i tried both
{{strategy.alert_message}}
{{strategy.alert.message}}

i tried contacting 3 commas as well, they simply have no idea why its happening i feel really down i worked a lot on the strategy and now its not going throw

Comment: Maybe message me on TV bro I could help more than on this thread

Comment: Also feel free to accept any of these answers haha